# access the values assigned in javascript via id in select_tag in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to access that values I assigned in javascript in the select_tag.

My javascript is following:

```
  function select_pk2(cell){
  var val = $('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_1').val();
  var t = $('#query_form_select_ops').val()
  var opts = JSON.parse($('#query_form_select_ops').val()); 

  var pk2 = JSON.stringify(opts[val]["rows"])
  var pk3 = JSON.stringify(opts[val]["cols"])

  $('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_2').val(pk2)
  $('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_3').val(pk3) 

  }
</script>
```

pk2 and pk3 are the arrays (like pk2 = ["aa","bb"]), so I expected that

```
<%= select_tag "query_form[opt][#{row}][2]",   :class => "table_column_width_2" %>  
<%= select_tag "query_form[opt][#{row}][3]",   :class => "table_column_width_2" %>
```

would have the values I assigned to them in javascript, namely pk2 and pk3, but somehow it is not working. How should I assigned the values for the select_tag given the id (query_form_opt_)?

Comment: Are you trying to set the select values or set the select options to choose from? Cause your question isn't clear enough about that.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to select value in selected box you should use value of option.
For adding options to select box you should create option element. Looks like:

```
$.each(pk2, function(value) {   
     $('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_2')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value", value)
         .text(value)); 
  });
```

For select options in this select box:

```
$('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_2').val(pk2[position_of_option_to_select])
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are choosing elements in your javascript based on the id attribute of the select element, but you're not setting the id on the select, when you do the `select_tag` call.  Rails may assign an id by default but it's not likely to be the same as the one you use in your JS.

try changing your select_tags to have the form

```
<%= select_tag "query_form[opt][#{row}][2]",   :class => "table_column_width_2", :id => "query_form_opt_#{row}_2" %>
```

Comment: it still does not assign the values. Do I need to preprocess the pk2 and pk3 arrays?

Comment: @max-williams: Won't the id be already generated by `select_tag`?

Comment: select_tag will auto generate an ID but it will make a very simple one, which might be duplicated by other select_tags on the page.  If you are doing javascript which expects the id to be a specific value then you should make sure that you set that id on the element.  Otherwise you're just gambling.